# python requests .status_code not returning correct value

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Looking at the documentation here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

This should print `200` and it does.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://souke.xdf.cn/Category/1-40-0-0.html?v=5&page=1&pagesize=50')
print r.status_code
```

This should print `404` but it prints `200`

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://souke.xdf.cn/CategoryXXX/1-40-0-0.html?v=5&page=1&pagesize=50')
print r.status_code
```

Why is that?

Is there another way to recognize a `404` error has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with `requests` but with the site you're accessing. It's returning `200`.

You can confirm this by looking at the headers using something like the Chrome developer tools:

```
Request URL:http://souke.xdf.cn/CategoryXXX/1-40-0-0.html?v=5&page=1&pagesize=50
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Comment: I see, then how do I get python to recognize that it is supposed to be a `404` error? Is there another method?

Comment: @jason_cant_code There's no method that will do it because `request` isn't doing anything wrong: the remote server is. So the best solution would be to ask the site to fix their server. Otherwise, you're stick with creating site-specific heuristics, like parsing the request content and looking for '404' in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The page you are looking for is found on the server , therefore the server responded with a 200 OK.
Nevertheless you can use Requests's raise_for_status() , to raise an exception whenever a server error is found, like 404 , 401 and so on.

```
import requests

>>>>r = requests.get('http://something.com/404/')
>>>>print r.status_code
404
>>>>r.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "requests/models.py", line 832, in raise_for_status
raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.raise_for_status()
```

this will raise error if not 200

this is better than using

```
.status_code
```